# Direct sum of projective module

Tags: modules, projective-module, direct-sum

Let $\left\{ P_{i}\right\} _{i\in I}$ be a family of $R$-module. I know that if each $P_{i}$ is projective then $\oplus_{i\in I}P_{i}$ is projective. Is the converse true, i.e if $\oplus_{i\in I}P_{i}$ is a projective module, is $P_{i}$ projective module for all $i\in I$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes its true. $P$ is projective iff there is free module $F$ such that $F=P\oplus Q$. Now if $\bigoplus P_i$ is projective then there is free module $F$ such that $F=\bigoplus P_i\oplus Q=P_i\oplus(\bigoplus_{j\neq i}P_i\oplus Q)$. This means that $P_i$ is projective.

Answer (score -2):

This is true. For injective modules,the corresponding results hold.